# Android: Make a ListItem Flash when tapped

Tags: android, listview

I have a simple ListItem defined below I use in a ListView. How can I make it "flash" so that users know what listview item they tapped?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IconImageView"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CaptionTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20dip" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ValueTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textColor="@color/icongrey" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the item is selected, why not just change the background, and if you need to, create a new thread that will just go to sleep, then change the item color back.

If you create a new thread, then create a subclass so you can pass in the selected item to it, or at least the item number, in case they touch multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

add a background to your root element
`android:background="@drawable/item_click"` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_pressed="false" />
```